# Do Apple TestFlight apps expire 90 days only in the TestFlight app and/or 90 days on the actual device?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

What happens to a TestFlight app after 90 days if there are no builds (since a build would reset the clock). Would the app in TestFlight simply not be downloadable and/or would the app running on the iOS device also expire (no longer be usable) after 90 days?

My goal is the have the app available beyond 90 days without the user needing to download the a new build from TestFlight.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to download it from TestFlight.app and launching it will "kill it immediately". You might see it as a "crash on launching".

Comment: Both. The build is limited to 90 days, period.

Comment: Thanks. Please post as answer. How long is Adhoc valid for? A year?

Comment: This is all well documented by Apple. There is really no need to use SO bandwidth on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From **[Testing Apps with TestFlight](https://testflight.apple.com)** website:

> Each build is available to test for up to 90 days, starting from the day the developer uploads their build. You can see how many days you have left for testing under the app name in TestFlight.

I have been experiencing this before. After 90 days, the app is not available to download anymore and existing app in real device will be unable to open. When you tap the app, it will quit immediately like a force close or fatal error. To resolve this 90 days limitation, the developer should upload a new build. Once the app is accepted, all TestFlight user will see a new update in their TestFlight app.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. For Adhoc, how long can the app be used for before Apple disables use?